# How do I install libgcrypt11 on Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I've been trying to install adobe-brackets on Kali Linux but there's a file dependency (on libgcrypt11), and Kali Linux no longer has that file by default (I've read that it used to be there, but Offensive Security decided to remove it). How do I get this file?

Comment: How did you try to install the adobe-brackets? Include this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`libgcrypt11` : You can just download the package https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libgcrypt11/download → libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u4_amd64.deb ... and install it : 1) `cd Downloads/` ... 2) # `gdebi ./libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u4_amd64.deb`

Quite simple : No conflicts, and usually no dependencies.